# CSS/Javascript: How to count the number of displayed lines of an element?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a simple way to count the number of lines of a display:inline-block element? I need to know how may lines the child elements are arranged into. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No there's no simple way. You'd have to use javascript and do some maths. To get the height of a line you'd need to get the font-size and add the line spacing. Then divide this by the element height.